# If... else statement

Tags: javascript

Even if the button has a "Stop timer", it runs the code within the "Start timer" IF, inside the function `TimerOnOff()`:

```
document.getElementById('BtnTimerOnOff').textContent = "Stop timer"



    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <script>

        var milisec=0
        var seconds=0
        document.d.d2.value='0'
        var onoff=0;


        function display(){
            if (milisec>=9){
                milisec=0;
                seconds+=1
            }
            else
                milisec+=1
            document.d.d2.value=seconds+"."+milisec
            setTimeout("display()",100)
        }

        function TimerOnOff(){
            var a = document.getElementById('BtnTimerOnOff').textContent

            //var b;
            alert(document.getElementById('BtnTimerOnOff').textContent)

            if (document.getElementById('BtnTimerOnOff').textContent = "Start timer") {
                document.getElementById('BtnTimerOnOff').textContent = "Stop timer"
                a = document.getElementById('BtnTimerOnOff').textContent
                alert(document.getElementById('BtnTimerOnOff').textContent)
                alert('aaa')
                display()
            }
            else if (document.getElementById('BtnTimerOnOff').textContent = "Stop timer"){
                    a = document.getElementById('BtnTimerOnOff').textContent
                    alert("Stop the timer")
            }
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<table border="0">
    <tr>
        <button type= "button" id="BtnTimerOnOff" onclick="TimerOnOff()">Start timer</button></tr>
    <td align="center" ><font face="JuraLight" size="6"><strong>Online Time:</strong></font></td>
    <td id="timer" align="center"><form name="d">
        <p><input type="text" size="8" name="d2"></p>
    </form>
    </td>
    <td align="center"><font face="Arial" size="6"><strong>seconds!</strong></font></td>
    </tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The Probelm**
You're not stopping the timer. When you call `display()` that'll run indefinitely. You need to use a flag or something.

I played around with your code a bit and came out with this - http://jsbin.com/xusasatewi/1/edit?html,console,output

Answer (score 1):

A single `=` sign is used to assign a value to a variable. You want to use `==` or `===` to compare/check values.

Answer (score 1):

when your evaluating the value in the If statement you need `==` not `=`

Answer (score 1):

When checking for equality in `if` conditions, you need to use a double-equals `==` or triple-equals `===`.

Do this:

```
if (document.getElementById('BtnTimerOnOff').textContent == "Start timer")
```

not this:

```
if (document.getElementById('BtnTimerOnOff').textContent = "Start timer")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

```
    var milisec=0
    var seconds=0
    document.d.d2.value='0'
    var onoff=0;


    function display(){
        if (milisec>=9){
            milisec=0;
            seconds+=1
        }
        else
            milisec+=1
        document.d.d2.value=seconds+"."+milisec
        setTimeout("display()",100)
    }

    function TimerOnOff(){
        var a = document.getElementById('BtnTimerOnOff').textContent

        //var b;
        alert(document.getElementById('BtnTimerOnOff').textContent)

        if (document.getElementById('BtnTimerOnOff').textContent === "Start timer") {
            document.getElementById('BtnTimerOnOff').textContent = "Stop timer"
            a = document.getElementById('BtnTimerOnOff').textContent
            alert(document.getElementById('BtnTimerOnOff').textContent)
            alert('aaa')
            display()
        }
        else if (document.getElementById('BtnTimerOnOff').textContent === "Stop timer"){
                a = document.getElementById('BtnTimerOnOff').textContent
                alert("Stop the timer")
        }
    }
</script>
```

Start timer
    **Online Time:**

**seconds!**

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to use `==` or `===` instead of `=` in the if statement: `if (document.getElementById('BtnTimerOnOff').textContent = "Start timer") {` should be `if (document.getElementById('BtnTimerOnOff').textContent == "Start timer") {`

`=` is an assignment operator, e.g. If you run `var x = 1;` then `x` will have the value of `1`.

`==` is a comparison operator that checks if the value of something is equal to the value of something else. e.g. `if(x == 1)` will evaluate to `true` and so will `if(x == true)` because `1` will evaluate to `true` and `0` evaluate to `false`.

`===` is another comparison operator that checks if the value of something is equal to the value of, and is the same type as something else. e.g. `if(x === 1)` will evaluate to `true` however, `if(x === true)` will evaluate to `false` because `1` (the value of `x`) is an `integer` and `true` is a `boolean`.

Also, you should save the timeout in a variable: `var timeout = setTimeout("display()",100);` so you can clear it to stop the timer: `clearTimeout(timeout);`